# Official support of Ubuntu 16.04 for raspberry pi 3

Tags: 16.04, raspberrypi, arm64

I've been searching for this topic and what I mostly find references to an unofficial build and also a 32-bit build.

Does anybody know if Canonical plans to release an officially supported 64-bit build of Ubuntu 16.04 for the raspberry pi 3?.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find info related ti the solution: [Ubuntu arm64/AArch64
on wiki.ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Ubuntu_arm64.2FAArch64)

> To check your chip:
>
> ```
> cat /proc/cpuinfo
> ```
>
> There is a `config.txt` entry to make the ARM start in 64-mode (otherwise 32-bit mode is used):

```
arm_control=0x200
```

> (This will fail to boot unless you provide a kernel compiled for 64-bit mode) 64 bit versions of the linux-raspi2 kernels were introduced in Ubuntu 16.10 (Yakkety Yak).
>
> The generic arm64 linux kernels can also be used with a suitable bootloader. For example, the [Zesty mini.iso](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/zesty/main/installer-arm64/current/images/netboot/) can be booted with a `u-boot-UEFI-grub2 combination` from SuSE for example.